# Wlan driver fails to auto-load in Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

I installed Xubuntu 14.04 on my dad's laptop, it has a Broadcom 43 wireless chip that works fine with the wl driver, but it fails to load at boot. If I run

```
sudo modprobe wl
```

, the wlan connects instantly, so I can make it work by doing that after each startup. How can I eliminate the need to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `wl` to `/etc/modules`. The top of `/etc/modules` says:

```
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.
```

Comment: It should be there in `/etc/modprobe.d/...`